# In Xamarin.Android, Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat Error raised on building project

Tags: android, xamarin.android, nuget-package

I am getting this error after messing with some package versions and adding **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat** package for my Xamarin.Android project targetting **Android 6**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
```

Please help me get my project built.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs for version mismatching between depended packages. You've got to remove this **Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat** package from the project along with other mismatching packages. *(What does mismatching means here is, if your target Android version is Android 6, all packages listed in the **packages.config** file should have **targetFramework="monoandroid60"** packages. If any package won't abide this, it's a mismatching version)*. If you have messed with versions, then removing the references and clean building alone won't work. You've got to remove all the mismatching packages from the **Nuget Package Manager** *(Tools **>** NuGet Package Manager **>** Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...)*. Note that when you're to remove these packages, you'll also need to remove the depended packages. No harm go ahead and remove them all and you can re-install them with the correct version.

Once you've removed the packages along with their dependent packages, try building the project. After a successful build, re-install the packages from the **Nuget Package Manager** with the **correct version**. *(Package versions are listed according to the API levels, **Ex:** Android 6 which is API 23, would support packages of version 23.x.x)*

Cleanup the project and build it, hopefully it'll succeed building!

Hope this'll help cleanup the mess!